# understanding "lifting" method in Hensel's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am having trouble understanding how "lifting" works here.  They began by finding solutions $2$ and $3$ for $x^2\equiv 14 \text{ mod}(5)$ and then insert $(2+5t)$ into $x$ for the expression $x^2\equiv 14 \text{ mod}(25)$. Why does inserting $(2+5t)$ give solutions to $25$?

and the image is from the article on "brilliant" under "Hensel's lemma".

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea behind the Hensel Lemma is the following:

Lets say you want to solve 
$$x^2\equiv 14 \text{ mod}(625)$$

Note that if $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $d|n$ then $a \equiv b \pmod{d}$.

Therefore
$$x^2 \equiv 14 \pmod{625} \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 14 \equiv 4 \pmod{5,25,125} (*) $$

Now, you go step by step modulo $5$, then $25$ then $125$. 
$$x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{5}$$

Lets look at the first solution:
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$
means $5|(x-2)$ and hence $x-2=5t$. Now, you go to the next step in (*): you know by (*) that 
$$x^2 \equiv 14 \pmod{25}$$ and you just deduced that 
$$x=2+5t$$
Plugging this in here you get that $x \equiv \mbox{something} \pmod{25}$ and hence $x-\mbox{something}=25s$. You next use this relation in the next step in $(*)$, and repeat.